# Print a PDF file using PrinterJob in Java

Tags: java, printing, java-print

I have an issue when trying to print a PDF file using Java. Here is my code:

```
PdfReader readFtp = new PdfReader();    // This class is used for reading a PDF file
PDDocument document = readFtp.readFTPFile(documentID);

printRequestAttributeSet.add(new PageRanges(1, 10));

job.setPageable(document);
job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);    // calling for print

document.close()
```

I use *`document.silentPrint(job);`* and *`job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);`* - it works fine. If I use *`document.silentPrint(job);`* - I can't set the *`PrintRequestAttributeSet`*.

Can anyone tell me how to set the *PrintRequestAttributeSet*?

Answer (score 38):

**My Printer did not support native PDF printing.**

I used the open source library Apache PDFBox https://pdfbox.apache.org to print the PDF. The printing itself is still handeled by the PrinterJob of Java.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class PrintingExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/temp/example.pdf"));

        PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService("My Windows printer Name");

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
        job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
        job.print();

    }       

    private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
            if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {
                return printService;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's better to close the PDDocument, hence you would need a try catch and a finally, but overall ok!

Comment: @RenRen were you able to get the print status automatically with this method?

Comment: @Rose I did not use the print status back then. Just fire and forget.

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me to print a PDF with a plain JRE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet patts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    patts.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
    PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, patts);
    if (ps.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");
    }
    System.out.println("Available printers: " + Arrays.asList(ps));

    PrintService myService = null;
    for (PrintService printService : ps) {
        if (printService.getName().equals("Your printer name")) {
            myService = printService;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myService == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Printer not found");
    }

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/John Doe/Desktop/SamplePDF.pdf");
    Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
    printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
    fis.close();        
}
```

Comment: This only works on Linux, right? I believe on Windows there is no PDF renderer in Java, correct?

Comment: @Mirko Seifert This code won't work, my printer prints only unreadable characters instead my PDF doc.

Comment: The code only works with printers which are capable of interpreting the PDF on their own. I found some printers which do so (e.g., some HP LaserJet models), but I also experienced that some printers print the raw content of the PDF file (as text). In such a case you'll need to convert the PDF to an image (e.g., using Ghostview).

Comment: Although posted many years ago, this response still works today and saved me hours of development effort. Thank you, sir. Wherever you may be today, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me to print multiple PDF document with a print dialog:

```
public void printPDF()
{
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PrintService printService;
    if(printerJob.printDialog())
    {
        printService = printerJob.getPrintService();
    }
    DocFlavor docType = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

    for (//fetch documents to be printed)
    {
        DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
        final byte[] byteStream = // fetch content in byte array;
            Doc documentToBePrinted = new SimpleDoc(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream), docType, null);
        printJob.print(documentToBePrinted, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(“C:/mypdf.pdf”);
Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, null, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();
```

You can also follow [these steps](http://bfo.com/blog/2012/02/15/using_java_to_print_pdf_documents.html)

Comment: How he can print PDF without a DocFlavor?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename = "Path for PDF File"; 
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File (filename));

        //takes standard printer defined by OS
        PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        myPrintService = findPrintService("Your Printer Name");
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
        job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
        job.print();

    }       

    private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
            if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {
                return printService;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Use version 2.0.4 of Apache PDFBox.
If using Maven Project, include the following in the XML file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 2.0.4 is outdated

Comment: @FrozenFlame  were you able to get the print status automatically with this method?

Answer (score -1):

Pageable implementation of PDDocument is deprecated, use PDPageable adapter class instead and try setPrintable instead of setPageable:

```
job.setPrintable(new PDPageable(document));
```

Comment: hello new user!  a better example that shows how to set the PageRanges with your example would be nice as well as a reference to the javadoc apis and version

Comment: `PDFPageable` is not a valid parameter for the `PrintJob.setPrintable` method.