# Java print pdf doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, pdf, printing, java-print

I'm trying to print a PDF file with my local printer. The Problem is when I select the printer in the printer dialog and press the print button nothing happens, the dialog just closes. I don't get any Exceptions or Warnings, the printer is just not printing the PDF file. I don't know why this happens. I already tested it with three different Computers (Windows 7 & 10) and three different printers but always the same problem.

I also tried it with the PDFBox library like this:

```
try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Self/Desktop/test.pdf");
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    doc.load(fis);
    doc.print();
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex1){
    ex1.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException ex2){
    ex2.printStackTrace();
}catch(PrinterException ex3){
    ex3.printStackTrace();
}
```

and with the standard java way like this:

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(new Copies(1));
PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor,  aset);
if(ps.length == 0){
    throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");
}
PrintService myService = null;
for (PrintService printService : ps) {
    if (printService.getName().equals("HP17DC1C (HP Officejet Pro 8610)")) { 
        myService = printService;
        break;
    }
}

if (myService == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Printer not found");
}

try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Slef/Desktop/test.pdf");
    Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
    printJob.print(pdfDoc, aset);
    fis.close(); 
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex1){
    ex1.printStackTrace();
}catch(PrintException ex2){
    ex2.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException ex3){
    ex3.printStackTrace();
}
```

but both ways lead to the same problem. After the print dialog nothing happens. I'm using java version 8.66. Can anyone help me with this problem, I really need to print PDF files?

Comment: Could it be that these libs check the print permission and the pdf has the print restriction activated?

Comment: Can you pelase Check if a similar question helps you, 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-a-pdf-file-using-printerjob-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @ain no the print restriction isn't activated. I can print the PDF file manually with adobe reader but not with java..

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu I tried a lot of ways here on stackoverflow but all solutions lead to the same problem :/