# How to print PDF File in Java with Print Dialog

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I found a Java printing example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/print/use-printing-service-in-java/).

Unfortunately, trying to execute I got a exception

```
Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
at application.UsePrintingServiceInJava.main(UsePrintingServiceInJava.java:55)
```

I also tried to print a png using `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG` flavor instead of the pdf, this works fine. May there be a problem with the printer itself or do I have to change the code?

Moreover, if you have got a better solution to print a PDF file in Java, let me know.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18962278/34088)

Comment: @Gatusko - The solution shown in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-a-pdf-file-using-printerjob-in-java/18962278#18962278) seems to be correct, it sends a printjob to the printer (as I can see in the "printjob" window of Windows). Problem is that after a while the print job dissapears without effect: The document isn't printed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) solved my problem. I downloaded [pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar](http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/ftp.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/2.0.4/pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar) and added it to the build path.
Now executing the following code prints the desired .pdf file:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename = "C:/Users/Prodoxon/Documents/test.pdf"; 
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File (filename));

        //takes standard printer defined by OS
        PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
        job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
        job.print();

    }       

    private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
            if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {
                return printService;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   

}
```

Even if it shows no print dialog, I think it is a good solution if you just want to print a file.