# How to print a PDF with a physical printer without creating any GUI

Tags: java

I need to pick a PDF from a given path and send it to a physical printer to get it printed. Can anyone suggest what to do?

I tried, but it's printing undesired output and that continuously, even though my PDF has only 1 page.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-a-pdf-file-using-printerjob-in-java might help. Please provide code or explain the problem in brief.

Comment: I am selecting a pdf from a location

Comment: Did you try `Desktop.getDesktop().print()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510560/pdf-library-for-java