# Print to a PDF file JavaFX

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

Is there a way to print/export a collection of Panes containing Nodes to a PDF file in JavaFX? Each Pane represents an A4 page and contains Text and Webview elements as in the following image:

[image: Pane with Text and Webview elements]

The only workaround solution I found (with reference to [this blogpost](https://ijavayou.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/javafx-easy-way-to-save-scenesnodes-as-pdf/)) was to print the Pane Nodes using the JavaFX API and selecting a PDF printer such as CutePDF. The goal is to directly provide the ability to produce a PDF file directly without relying on an external PDF printer.

Comment: You could take a snapshot then use a PDF api to add the image to PDF. You could also use a PDF api to add the text to a PDF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-a-pdf-file-using-printerjob-in-java [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) or [iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java).

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks! I stumbled across [OpenPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) to assist in creating the PDF.