# How to print a PDF File using native JAVA (or open and print)

Tags: java, swing, printing, itext

I created a invoice billing software using itextpdf 5. Is there any way to print the generated PDF using java?

Comment: Have you tried something line [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-a-pdf-file-using-printerjob-in-java)?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. :(

Comment: You need to mention all the things you've tried otherwise we're just wasting time.  And of the top two answer, which did you try?

Comment: I tried using printer job, but I think my printer does not support native pdf printing.

Comment: *"I tried using printer job"* Copy/paste the output of the stack trace. This is a good time for more words, not less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using [`Desktop.print(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#print(java.io.File)).